# OpenLayers zoom using smaller increments

Tags: openlayers-2

Currently when the zoom control + and - are pressed, the map zooms a lot for each click. How to make the zoom increments smaller for each click.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that you are not using a third party map with fixed zoom levels (e.g. Google, Bing, OSM etc) you can set the scales or resolutions array of your map to what ever you would like - see the [documentation](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/SettingZoomLevels) for full details.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @iant's answer, if you are using a third party map with fixed zoom levels you can still zoom smaller amounts when scrolling and using a PanZoomBar (I don't know if it applies to pressing the zoom in/out buttons) by using [ClientZoom](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/clientzoom.html) and [fractionalZoom](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/fractional-zoom.html), which essentially allow you to zoom to arbitrary zooms by making the map tiles 'stretch' when you zoom to a level in between the standard zoom levels.

The best way to understand this is to just try out the examples I linked to. You could then [check out the docs](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.fractionalZoom) to see how it is done. I'm afraid I'venever properly tried it, so I can't help much more than that, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box - I don't believe this is possible.  Since tiles are customarily 256x256 - then within each zoom level that tile size is multiplied by 2.

Meaning:
Zoom level 0: 256 px
Zoom level 1: 512 px
Zoom level 2: 1024 px
Zoom level 3: 2048 px
Zoom level 4: 4096 px
Zoom level 5: 8192 px
....etc